# Javascript in JSP

Tags: javascript, jsp

```
try {
  <%if(lBlnBlockScreen){%>
    UTIL_FORM.fVarForm = document.all.frmMain;
    UTIL_FORM.fVarInclude = [
      document.getElementById('INT_GENDER_DROPDOWN'),
      .
      .  
      .
      document.getElementById('INT_JOIN_calender')
    ];
    UTIL_FORM.fnDisableAll();
    document.frmMain.CancelButton.style.display = '';
    document.frmMain.Benefit.style.display = '';
    document.frmMain.DepButton.style.display= '';
    document.frmMain.Companion.style.display= '';
    document.frmMain.Nominee.style.display= '';
  <%}%>
} catch(e) {
      alert(e.message);
}
    fnSetMandatory();       
}
```

Juz wan to clarify that the above try-catch conditon work or not work? Since the lBlnBlockScreen variable did not consists of value? how can i printout the value of the lBlnBlockScreen ?

In additon, does this method work `UTIL_FORM.fnDisableAll()` because it seem did not being called. If possible, please help to clarify whether the above code works well or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters, do not use:

```
document.all.frmMain
```

This is IE only code. use this instead:

```
UTIL_FORM.fVarForm = document.forms['frmMain'];
```

Now, with this, *if* you have defined a method "fnDisableAll()" that is attached to your UTIL_FORM object, (and your JSP condition is true), then yes, it will be called.

Note:
To clarify... all of your document.all or document.frmMain statements should either use the DOM0 method of extracting the elements from the document.forms collection or use the generic document.getElementsById(id) or document.getElementsByName(name) methods.

```
var myForm = document.forms[NameOrIndex];
//or
var myForm = document.getElementById(IdOfForm);
//or
var myForm = document.getElementsByName(NameOfForm)[0];
```